# Ignoring .gitignore when running git archive

Tags: git

I have a git repo with a bunch of source code, and when that compiles a bunch of binaries are produced. The binaries are all listed in appropriate .gitignore files, and not included in the repo.

However, I would like to distribute a source+binaries snapshot zipfile of my repo that contains all the binaries, but not things like the .git/ directory.

It would seem like the natural way to create a snapshot zipfile would be

```
git archive -o archive.zip
```

But that doesn't include any of the binaries which are in .gitignore.

Ideas on how I can accomplish this with git archive? (My work-around is to manually create a zip archive that includes everything other than the .git/ directory)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you are going to be able to use 'git archive' for what you hope to achieve.  'git archive' works on commits and your binary files simply won't be visible.  Note 'git archive' is so commit centric that you can use git archive directly in a bare repository where no source controlled files exist explicitly.

Answer (score 9):

You can exclude files and/or directories from `git archive` by using the **.gitattributes** file.

1. Create a file named **.gitattributes** in your project root (if it doesn't exist).
2. Edit the file: Each exclusion should have a file pattern followed by "**export-ignore**":

   ```
   .gitattributes export-ignore
   .gitignore export-ignore
   /mytemp export-ignore
   ```
3. Make sure to ignore the .gitattributes file itself!
4. Make sure to commit the .gitattributes file, or `git archive` won't pick up the settings.

Then feel free to use your `git archive -o archive.zip` command, or variant.

[Source here](https://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/excluding-files-from-git-archive/)

Comment: @akeshet isn't asking how to ignore files, but asking how to ignore the `.gitignore`. In other words, how to include files that are ignored in version control.

Comment: Might not have answered the asker's question, but it answered mine when the search engine sent me here.

Comment: This is the best answer that didn't answer the question. This was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 7):

It is not possible to include files in a git-archive if they are ignored (via `.gitignore`) from version control.

In my workaround, I append the files I need afterwards.

```
git archive --format=tar -o repo.tar HEAD
tar --append --file=repo.tar thirdparty/binary
gzip repo.tar
```

Note that appending to a `tar.gz` isn't easy, so I first create an uncompressed archive first, then add the binaries, then compress.

Answer (score 1):

As [GoZoner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1286639/gozoner) [states](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10098081/520162), this is no task that could be done with `git archive`.

Use the right tools for the right tasks. I do something very similar too and have a Perl script that creates my archive containing the sources and the compiled stuff.

Simply zipping up everything that was created during compilation is probably not what you want:

- If you want to hand over a library to someone, he will only be interested in the library and some headers to be able to use the library. No need to archive object files and other intermediate stuff for example.
- If you want your audience to be able to build the library by themselves, include the sources, the needed project files and maybe a pre-built binary.
- ...

So, from my experience, I would recommend to take the script language of your choice and use the provided mechanisms of the language to create your distribution. Doing so, you could also create a different folder structure in your distribution that doesn't have to match the structure on your disk.

To note the git revision from which the archive was created, you could store the revision in the zip file comments:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: How you save the comment using git archive?

Comment: @alexis: you cannot. Thr shown archive was created using a Perl script.